# What is difference between $('abc') and $("abc") in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between $('.abc') and $(".abc") in jQuery?

Example:

```
var main = function() {
 $('.btn').click(function(event) {
   $('.container').hide();
 });
};
```

vs

```
var main = function() {
 $(".btn").click(function(event) {
   $(".container").hide();
 });
};
```

Both of the code snippets work well. So what is different?

Comment: Single and double quotes have nothing to do with jQuery, it's an element of JavaScript. But there is no difference in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, there isn't any difference between single or double quotes.

Comment: Thanks @Mr Ob. I got it.

Comment: There is one difference... They are delimited by different characters. `'a'+'b'` means something different than `"a'+'b"`

Answer (score 4):

They are exactly the same. JavaScript strings can be delimited by either single or double quotes.

Comment: I just updated my question. Both of code are correct ?

Comment: @Don Indeed, there is no difference between the two snippets you had.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much, @Chris Jester-Young :)

Answer (score 2):

No difference; they both are missing a class or ID selector.

Comment: I just updated my question.

Comment: Unlike some other languages, JavaScript makes no distinction between single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings; so both will works fine.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.